# Windows application consumes too much memory. Any advices?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Visual studio 2008 application using C++ under windows XP.

Any useful advices beyond the "always delete new objects" advice?

Edit: Actually I am looking for some programming advices.

Comment: Buy more memory? Either that or run a memory profiler. It's silly to give generic advice for this type of a situation. Figure out *where* your memory leaks are, and then fix them.

Comment: It's not clear from your question if the application is leaking memory or if it just consumes a lot of memory because it needs to keep a lot of data in memory at the same time?

Comment: Where does memory go? Is it leaked or actually used?

Comment: which memory you are talking about physical or virtual?

Comment: @Naveen: What's the difference? (Obviously I mean to the Windows programmer, not in general.)

Comment: Or you could kill other bg processes that are running to save you some precious memory, but this might only result in negligible gain + you'd need to know what to kill.

Comment: @Cody Gray: I believe it does make a difference. If the virtual memory consumption is too much, then it is most probably a memory leak. If the physical memory consumption is too much then it may be because of the caching strategy used by the OS for calls such as `MapViewOfFileEx`.

Comment: I think that in order to realistically answer this, we're going to need more information. There are lots of techniques that might help, but crucially, they *depend on what you are doing*.

Comment: Like the others said, we need more info.
Too much memory compared to what? What are the requirements for memory usage?
What is the functional problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what you mean by "consumes too much memory".

A) By design i.e. it requires to load or generate large data structures that you expect to cause problems.

In this case is it i) too much phyical memory i.e. it becomes slow because the hard drive starts swapping pages in and out or ii) too much address space i.e. it fails to allocate because it can't find a hole in the memory?

For ii) consider using 64bit builds, consider using shared memory to store large data structures, beware of fragmentation - allocate large buffers early, break up large data structures into smaller ones

B) It surprises you by using loads of memory.

Find your leaks or bugs - various profilers available or visual studio built in debug alloc hooks.  Do you have any broken arithmetic for calculating buffer sizes(especially accidental int wrap around)?

Use smart pointers to manage deletion.

Comment: Basically my application receives messages from MSMQ and logs them in a database (SQL Server).

Comment: @Chrys - Are you freeing your MQ resources as well as your unused Db resources ?

Comment: Actually my mistake was that I didn't follow the advice I wrote above (always delete new objects). Thanks for the advices though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a memory leak, there's a free solution to throw at the problem before buying/running other profiles, and that's UMDH. It can detect most memory leaks, if that's your situation.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/268343